# Video.js — не работает HLS на Android

Tags: html5, online-video

В новой версии Video.js встроили HLS. При вставке ссылки на HLS файл видео на Android или тормозит, или вообще не работает. На iOS не тестировали. На Smart TV и ПК нормально. Пробовали устанавливать старую версию плеера и уже плагином подключать HLS, но ничего не изменилось. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <video style="margin: 0 auto"
               id="my-video"
               class="video-js "
               controls
               preload="auto"
               width="1080"
               height="640"
               poster="1.jpg"
               data-setup="{}"
        >
            <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

так сделай. Для начало webm format. теперь mp4. Проблема не будеть